# How to correctly update redux state in ReactJS reducer?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following structure in my Redux data store:

```
{
    filterData: {
        22421: {
            filterId: 22421,
            selectedFilters: [
                {
                    filterName: 'gender',
                    text: 'Male',
                    value: 'male'
                },
                {
                    filterName: 'gender',
                    text: 'female',
                    value: 'female'
                }
            ] 
        }   
        22422: {
            filterId: 22422,
            selectedFilters: [
                {
                    filterName: 'colour',
                    text: 'Blue',
                    value: 'blue'
                },
                {
                    filterName: 'animal',
                    text: 'sheep',
                    value: 'Sheep'
                }
            ] 
        }
```

Can someone point me towards using the correct way to update the selectedFilters array without mutating the state directly? i.e. How can I  add/remove elements in the selectedFilters array for a given filterId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it's done by using non mutating (ie. returning a new object, rather than modifying the existing one) operators and function:

- [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) for objects and arrays (for additions and edits),
- [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for arrays (for edits and removals),
- [assigning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for object (for edits and additions).

You have to do this on each level leading to the final one—where your change happens. In your case, if you want to change the `selectedFilters` on one of those objects you'll have to do something like that:

```
// Assuming you're inside a reducer function.
case SOME_ACTION:
  // Returning the new state object, since there's a change inside.
  return {
    // Prepend old values of the state to this new object.
    ...state,

    // Create a new value for the filters property,
    // since—again—there's a change inside.
    filterData: {
      // Once again, copy all the old values of the filters property…
      ...state.filters,

      // … and create a new value for the filter you want to edit.
      // This one will be about removal of the filter.
      22421: {
        // Here we go again with the copy of the previous value.
        ...state.filters[22421],

        // Since it's an array and we want to remove a value,
        // the filter method will work the best.
        selectedFilters: 
          state.filters[22421].selectedFilters.filter(
            // Let's say you're removing a filter by its name and the name
            // that needs to be removed comes from the action's payload.
            selectedFilter => selectedFilter.name !== action.payload
          )
      },
      // This one could be about addition of a new filter.
      22422: {
        ...state.filters[22422],

        // Spread works best for additions. It returns a new array
        // with the old values being placed inside a new one.
        selectedFilters: [
           // You know the drill.
          ...state.filters[22422].selectedFilters,

          // Add this new filter object to the new array of filters.
          {
            filterName: 'SomeName',
            text: 'some text',
            value: action.value // Let's say the value comes form the action.
          }
        ]
      },
    }
  }
```

This constant "copy old values" is required to make sure the values from nested objects are preserved, since the spread operator copies properties in a shallow manner.

```
const someObj = {a: {b: 10}, c: 20}
const modifiedObj = {...someObj, a: {d: 30}}
// modifiedObj is {a: {d: 30}, c: 20}, instead of
// {a: {b: 10, d: 30}, c: 20} if spread created a deep copy.
```

As you can see, this is a bit mundane to do. One solution to that problem would be to create some kind of nested reducers functions that will work on separate trees of the state. However, sometimes it's better not to reinvent the wheal and use tools that are already available that were made to solve those kind of problems. Like [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. I am trying to get it working when adding an element to the array so I'm trying to use that section of the code you provided. However, I'm getting the following error message: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" and selectedFilters is highlighted. Appreciate your help

Comment: Hard to say. Now that I see, I used `filters` rather than `filterData` in the response, so that's the first clue. Second one is that there should be `[...state.filters[22422].selectedFilters, /* new filter */]` (missing `selectedFilters` access) in the example. I've fixed both issues, so maybe that will help you. If not, you'll have to show your code.

Comment: Thanks your help. I managed to solve the issue, it was caused by me passing an incorrect value to an action.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a dedicated library for managing the immutable state (like suggested in another answer) take a look at [Immer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer#reducer-example).

I find that this library is *simpler* to be used than Immutable.js (and the bundle size will be smaller too)